# exclude url for swagger from web.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, web-applications, war

I used servlet mapping like

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and used fox-swagger 2.0 that contains UI html file that contains in webapp/docs folder of my project. So I could get swagger using docs/swagger-ui url and /rest/* for servlets. Now I change servlet url pattern to `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>` and now all requests proceed by servlets so can`t get swagger. I believe there is a way to exclude url for swagger but have no idea how to do it